# Why cant I go to this path? it says I don't have permission but I am the administrator

Tags: macbook-pro, permission, path

So I got grand perspective because I wanted to clean the 70gb worth of system and other storage on my Mac but this one file which im pretty sure I deleted long ago still shows up and is taking up a massive 6 gb of space so I decided to go delete it but after I followed the file path It keeps telling me I dont have permission what can I do?

this is the error
[image: error]

and this is the path
[image: path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even as an admin, you cannot by default see inside another user's private area. As this particular user is a deleted account, you can just add yourself to the list of users with privileges, without having to worry about any other consequences.

Select the user folder (jayeshghandi) then  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>i</kbd>  or right click > Get Info.
At the bottom of the panel, click the lock, then type your admin password.
Click the  <kbd>+</kbd>  button bottom left & in the window that pops up, select your own account name & then click Select.
Back in the Info window you will see you name has been added to the list.
Make sure it's set to Read & Write & them from the little 'gear' icon at the bottom, select 'Apply to enclosed items.
After a few seconds you will then have full admin access to the entire jayeshghandi folder.

Comment: thank you. very much! this fixed my problem but if I understand correctly these files in the 'deleted user' folder, they aren't used anymore are they? so is there any harm in deleting the entire jayeshgandhi folder?

Comment: As the user was deleted you can check if anything is still needed & if not you can delete any or all of it.